# Can not successfully add org.joda.time (2.4) library to Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, libraries

I have tried to add the library to Netbeans in the following ways:

`Project > Properties > Libraries > Add Jar/Folder`

`Project > Properties > Packaging > Add Jar/Folder`

`Tools > Libraries > Add Library > Add Jar/Folder`

`Tools > Options > Java > Classpath > Add Jar/Zip`

..and probably all their combinations and nothing seems to work. Any ideas what to try? When I type `import org.joda.time;` 
it doesn't find the library (`error: package org.joda does not exist`).

Comment: Make sure to add the jodatime library to your Compile-Time Libraries and not just your Run-Time Libraries

Answer (score 2):

Tested on Netbeans 7.0.1.
In the Projects window right-click on the name of the project -> Properties -> The Project Properties window opens. In Categories tree select "Libraries" node -> On the right side of the Project Properties window press button "Add JAR/Folder" -> Select jars you need.